# How to find an uncle of a tag with Jquery

Tags: jquery

When I click on an anchor in an li tag, I would like to identify the index of the h3 tag that precedes it.  For example, if I were to click on overview, I would like to get the index of Introduction.  How would I accomplish this with Jquery?

```
<h3><a href="Introduction" rel="address:/Introduction">Introduction</a></h3>
<div class="navigation primary_navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="purpose" rel="address:/purpose">Purpose</a></li>
        <li><a href="overview" rel="address:/overview">Overview</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<h3><a href="Incorporate_Learning" rel="address:/Incorporate_Learning">Incorporate Learning</a></h3>
<div class="navigation primary_navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="appraise" rel="address:/appraise">Appraise</a></li>
        <li><a href="select" rel="address:/select">Select</a></li>
        <li><a href="define" rel="address:/define">Define</a></li>
        <li><a href="execute" rel="address:/execute">Execute</a></li>
        <li><a href="resources" rel="address:/resources">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("li a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $h3 = $(this).closest(".primary_navigation").prev();
        console.log($("h3").index($h3));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly.  Makes sense now that I see it, I just couldn't wrap my head around it this morning.  Cheers. Stackoverflow is an awesome community.

Comment: Worth noting that this in the index in an array of every H3 on your page, not just your navigation section. In the sample code it will work, but a full on page might not return what you're after.

Comment: Very true, I'll make sure to add a class selector.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the index you can get all the previous `h3` from the point clicked.

Something like :

```
$(this).closest('div.navigation').prevAll('h3').length
```

Would return 2, when there's 2 elements, so your index is the length of previous h3's minus 1.

Comment: This seems like extra work to get the index. Why not just use the index function?

Comment: Why hit the DOM for all H3 elements when it's much more trivial to subtract one?

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
$('.navigation a').click(function(){
  var uncle = $(this).parents(".navigation").prev('h3');
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work

```
$("li").live("click", function(){
    alert($(this).parents('.navigation').prev().html());
});
```

Comment: it's about clicking on the link, not the list element

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li>a').click(function(){
    var uncle = $(this).parents('ul').parent().prev();
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyTj8/)